# Can't wrap a template static function with swig

Tags: templates, static, swig

I am trying to wrap a simple static template function like this:

```
namespace ns {
  class A {
   public:
    template<typename T>
    static void func() {}
  };
}
```

with the swig directive:

```
%template(func_type) ns::A::func<type>;
```

But I keep getting:

```
Error: Undefined scope 'ns::A'
Error: Template 'ns::A::func' undefined.
```

I have found the same issue asked on [this mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/programming.swig/2004-10/msg00163.html), but unfortunately there are no replies. Is this a swig limitation? Does it require some special operation?

---

Here are the few lines above ready to be pasted in .i file:

```
%module example
%{
namespace ns {
  class A {
   public:
    template<typename T>
    static void func() {}
  };
}
%}

%template(func_int) ns::A::func<int>;
```

To process this with swig just do:

```
swig -c++ -tcl test.i
```

Answer (score 0):

By now I solved this declaring some dummy functions that swig can manage better:

```
namespace ns {
  class A {
   public:
    template<typename T>
    static void func() {}

    static void funcT1() {func<T1>();}
    static void funcT2() {func<T2>();}
  };
}
```

I think it's clean enough, but still I am looking for a more proper solution.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give it a specific type:

```
%template(func_int) ns::A::func<int>;
%template(func_float) ns::A::func<float>;
```

You might also (can't test here) have to wrap the `%template` with namespace:

```
namespace ns {
    %template(func_int)   A::func<int>;
    %template(func_float) A::func<float>;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did but I encountered the error described. Did you try this? Were you successful?

Comment: Maybe you have to wrap with namespace (updated my answer). If that doesn't help, then there must be something else wrong in your .i. Perhaps extend your post to include a complete but *minimal* .i that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The complete and minimal .i was already almost there in the question, but I added it. I also tried your second suggestion but doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I put it there because I have it in the real code, but it really makes no difference. Without the template the errors are `Error: Undefined scope 'A'
Error: Template 'A::func' undefined.`